# Get all group names of logged user exists, using c# SharePoint 2013?

Tags: development

In SharePoint 2013, how do you get all group names of existing logged in user using c#?

Comment: Are you using Server object model or client object model?

Comment: Using Server Object Model.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can use:
I made another way to get te user and the group:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    getCurrentUser();
});
function getCurrentUserGroupColl(UserID)
 {
  $.ajax
  ({
  url: "/sites/dialogo/_api/web/GetUserById("+UserID+")/Groups",
  type: "GET",
  headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose","X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val() },
  dataType: "json",
  async: true,
   success: function(data){
      /* get all group's title of current user. */
      var results = data.d.results;
      for(var i=0; i< results.length; i++)
      {
            console.log(results[i].Title);
            var gp = results[i].Title;
            if(gp =="MyDefinedGroup")
            {
                //Do something
            }  
      }
  }
  });
}
function getCurrentUser()
{
 $.ajax
  ({
  url: "/sites/dialogo/_api/web/Currentuser",
  type: "GET",
  headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose","X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val() },
  dataType: "json",
  async: true,
  success: function(data){
    getCurrentUserGroupColl(data.d.Id)
  }
  });
}
```

*
sharepoint online (2013)
*

Comment: but question is for C#..